# Keynote - need individual letter graphics that can be moved/manipulated to create words on slide

Tags: graphics, keynote, font

I teach kids who failed to learn to read in school, online. I am making a series of presentations for very simple words like "is," etc.

I need to have some large alphabetic letters at the top of the screen that I can make bounce, slide down into place, and so on. I think they would be called graphics, but I don't know what phrase to use to search for on the web to locate some sets in various fonts. I found individual letter .jpgs/pics, but they all seem to have too much space on the sides to put them close enough for words.

I tried making my own by taking screenshots of each letter, but lots of them keep having a thin grey line show up on the pic. No clue how to stop the thin grey lines, but I know they'd interfere with my struggling kids' learning.,

I'm a graphics nincompoop, and know nothing. Any ideas or suggestions would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully enough, so my answer did not make sense so I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use text objects in Keynote to do what you want? Create a text object with the letter A, resize and colour it etc, create another text object with B, etc.

Comment: I'll go look up text object--it sounds like it might be just what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I looked a long time for how to make a text object, including the manual and some tutorials, but I haven't found it yet. Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: OK, I think you mean create a text box for each letter. I figured out how to do movements with graphics, but not with text boxes. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, Text Box is the term. Just follow these steps 1. create a new text box and replace the default text with the letter A. 2. Deselect this text box by tapping elsewhere in your view. 3. Select the A by tapping on it. 4. In the Build Inspector you can now move it, fade it, animate it, whatever.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I can't get it to move any direction but horizontally.

Comment: You want the 'action' tab in the Build Inspector. When this is selected and you select your text box you should get a ghost image connected by an umbilical cord to your text box - drag this to wherever you want it. You might also check out http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Keynote09_UserGuide.pdf‎ if you haven't already. Page 118 describes the Action Tab